# Recursively loop through array of objects to build an array of all possible routes with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

I'm trying to write a routing function that will return all possible routes from any two given locations (I'm calling them "spaces"), but I'm stuck on writing the recursive function.

My data will look something like this:

```
const allSpaces = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Living Room',
        connectedSpaces: [1,2]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Hallway A',
        connectedSpaces: [0,4]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Hallway B',
        connectedSpaces: [0,4]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Bedroom',
        connectedSpaces: [1,2]
    }
];
```

So, calling a `getAllRoutes(0,3)` method would walk all possible routes and return an array of arrays:

```
[
    [0,1,3],
    [0,2,3]
]
```

Keep in mind that this may not always be as simplistic of a dataset as my example (i.e., Hallway A could have an offshoot that provides an alternate route, or could re-intersect with previously visited spaces).

I'm pretty stumped. I've made several attempts at a recursive function but keep ending up with incomplete lists or infinite loops. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is called graph traversal.  Learn about Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

### Visualizing your data

Whenever you find yourself stuck with a problem like this, it helps to think of an easy way to visualize what's happening. To get a feel for the graph you're working with, I wrote a few lines of code to visualize the graph.

Through the visualization, I noticed there's probably a small error in the data. I figured spaces 1 and 2 should be connected to `0` and `3` rather than `0` and `4`. I adjusted this in the data, and added an additional space for testing.

If you like, you can check out the visualization by expanding the snippet below.

```js
const allSpaces=[{id:0,name:"Living Room",connectedSpaces:[1,2]},{id:1,name:"Hallway A",connectedSpaces:[0,3,4]},{id:2,name:"Hallway B",connectedSpaces:[0,3]},{id:3,name:"Bedroom",connectedSpaces:[1,2]}, {id:4,name:"Master bedroom",connectedSpaces:[1]}];

const Edge = (() => {
  // Do not support two way edges. Cache from and to internally:
  const cache = new Map();
  const Edge = (from, to) => {
    const id = `${Math.min(from, to)}.${Math.max(from, to)}`;
    const length = 1;
    
    if (!cache.has(id)) {
      cache.set(id, { from, to, id, length });
    }
    
    return cache.get(id);
  }
  
  return (from => to => Edge(from, to));
})();

const edges = uniques(allSpaces.reduce(
  (edges, node) => edges.concat(
    node.connectedSpaces.map(Edge(node.id))
  ), []
));

const Node = ({ id, name }) => ({ id, label: name });
const nodes = allSpaces.map(Node);

const network = new vis.Network(
  document.getElementById("cvs"), 
  { nodes, edges }, 
  {}
);

function uniques(arr) { return Array.from(new Set(arr).values()); }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis-network.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.21.0/vis.min.js"></script>
<div id="cvs" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Being able to see our data, makes it easier to check if our function works! Now, you've asked to find *all* paths to get from A to B. Note that this the number of possible paths can *very quickly* increase as you add more nodes. (e.g., have a look at the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)).

### Shortest path?

If you're really looking for the *shortest* path, you might want to adapt the code below to use [Dijkstra's Shortest Path algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode), as SLaks suggested in their comment.

### Brute force approach

But, since the example set is small, and you asked for *all* routes, let's brute force it:

- Define an empty collection of paths
- Define a start node
- Add its id to the current path
- For every node it links to:

  - Check if it's our destination; if so: return the collection with the current path added
  - Check if it's already in our path; if so: skip it (we don't want to move in circles)
  - If it's not in our path nor our destination, add it to the path and move deeper

Or, in code:

```
const walk = (destination, paths, path, node) => {
  // Walking in circles
  if (path.includes(node.id)) // <-- expensive, for large paths use a Set
    return paths;

  // End reached
  if (node.id === destination)
    return paths.concat([path.concat(node.id)]);

  // Take next step recursively
  return node.connectedSpaces
    .reduce(
      (acc, id) => walk(destination, acc, path.concat(node.id), spaceMap.get(id)),
      paths
   );
}
```

Here's a running snippet you can use to step through and see what happens:

```js
const allSpaces=[{id:0,name:"Living Room",connectedSpaces:[1,2]},{id:1,name:"Hallway A",connectedSpaces:[0,3,4]},{id:2,name:"Hallway B",connectedSpaces:[0,3]},{id:3,name:"Bedroom",connectedSpaces:[1,2]}, {id:4,name:"Master bedroom",connectedSpaces:[1]}];

const spaceMap = new Map(allSpaces.map(s => [s.id, s]));

const walk = (destination, paths, path, node) => {
  // Walking in circles
  if (path.includes(node.id)) // <-- expensive, for large paths use a Set
    return paths;
  
  // End reached
  if (node.id === destination)
    return paths.concat([path.concat(node.id)]);
   
  // Take next step recursively
  return node.connectedSpaces
    .reduce(
      (acc, id) => walk(destination, acc, path.concat(node.id), spaceMap.get(id)),
      paths
   );
}

const calcRoute = (from, to) => {
  const routes = walk(to, [], [], spaceMap.get(from));
  
  return `
Found ${routes.length} route(s) to ${spaceMap.get(to).name}
${routes.map(r => r.map(id => spaceMap.get(id).name).join(" -> ")).join("\n")}
  `;
}

console.log(calcRoute(0, 3));
console.log(calcRoute(0, 4));
```